# Retrofit2 - JSON Array Parsing

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit to parse json, and after parsing it will give pojo objects. I want store data to sqlite so I'm extracting data from pojo to store it in db. Is this a good approach?
Because retrofit converts json to pojo and again I have to extract pojo to get data. This is time consuming; any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

It is good approach as it keeps your data organised. The only part I didn't understand is what do you mean by extacting from pojo.

For insert or update operation you should use pojo instead of directly using json object or string.

Converting json to pojo keeps data ready for showing on UI as well as Storing in database without complex code.

For time managment I would suggest check out **Suger ORM** it will save you some time.

Hope it was helpful.